# Laravel 4: Installation error on Windows 8 XAMPP/WAMP

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I am trying to install Laravel 4 but I keep geting this error. If you have any hints on how to solve it, I would appreciate your help.

Here is want i tried so far

- enabled php extensions: **php_openssl, php_curl, php_socket**
- In Apache Modules, enabled **ssl_module**
- in the all php.ini files i enebaled **openssl**
- Disabled Firewall

---

My configuration:

- Windows 8
- Using Git Bash
- Tried on both XAMPP/WAMPP and i get the same error
- Composer is installed

  ```
  $ composer create-project laravel/laravel project-v1 --prefer-dist

    [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
    The "http://packagist.org/p/laravel/laravel$cfb9a31046c5c103d3b5e46a51b5a18
    a629de734f094f489e2b7df1420078c17.json" file could not be downloaded: send
    of 103 bytes failed with errno=10053 An established connection was aborted
    by the software in your host machine.

    send of 21 bytes failed with errno=10053 An established connection was abor
    ted by the software in your host machine.

    send of 113 bytes failed with errno=10053 An established connection was abo
    rted by the software in your host machine.

    send of 2 bytes failed with errno=10053 An established connection was abort
    ed by the software in your host machine.

    send of 2 bytes failed with errno=10053 An established connection was abort
    ed by the software in your host machine.

    failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!



  create-project [-s|--stability="..."] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repos
  itory-url="..."] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--n
  o-scripts] [--no-progress] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [package] [directory] [ve
  rsion]
  ```

Comment: Get this error too with Wamp on win 7 and I'm trying for laravel 4 with a composer.json nothing in it except {"require":{     "laravel/laravel": "dev-develop" }} then running composer install from git bash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, if you're running a web filter, especially *K9 Web Protection*, uninstall that first and retry. If the problem persists, read ahead:

The problem is that Composer downgrades to *http* requests after the first *https* request to the server. This is done to improve performance/speed and to ensure file integrity/security via the sha256 hashes. In any case, this will cause a 10053 error (errno=10053 An established connection was aborted by the software on your host machine ... failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!) on some machines.

The reason this happens to some people and not others seems to be the manner in which your ISP handles *http* requests. In my case, they're re-routed through a caching proxy; which doesn't work well with the way Composer crafts its *http* requests. That's what happened to me - others may have a different cause. In any case, the fix is to force Composer to use *https* requests instead of *http* requests:

Add the following to your Composer installation's config file (composer.json). In Windows, you may find this file at C:\Users{Your Username}\AppData\Roaming\Composer.

```
"repositories": [
{
    "packagist": false
},
{
    "type": "composer",
    "url": "https://packagist.org/"
}
],
```

Then go ahead and create your project again as you had attempted. It should work now.

Comment: Dude, I had K9 Web Protection installed and uninstalling it solved the problem for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have some kind of firewall running on your local machine that is blocking the connection to download the required files.

You will need to shuffle through any security programs and check if any are blocking it.