# Composer windows installer

Tags: composer-php

I want to install composer on windows to start using laravel, but I encounter the following issue when running the windows installer:

```
Composer Error [ERR_DOWNLOAD]: Composer was not downloaded
```

Clicking retry does not resolve the issue. I'm running WAMP and I have enabled open_ssl in the correct php.ini and can see from `phpinfo()` that it's enabled. I'm trying to understand how to complete the manual installation, but I'm not understanding the steps outlined here properly: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#manual-installation

Do I need to add php.exe or composer to my system variables before I follow through the instructions in the link above?

Comment: If PHP is not installed or not in your path, then composer will not work.

Comment: @vascowhite thanks for your comment. I added php.exe, the php folder and C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin to the path, as mentioned in the installer (don't know how I missed that before!) and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: If you are on windows, then I would recommend using the installer. https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe

Comment: @vascowhite Yes I am on windows and the installer is what I'm having trouble with. Please reread the question.

Comment: facing the same problem..

Comment: @AbhishekGoel cracked this last night for my home PC still a problem on work PC though. I think the major thing was removing k9 protection software that I had running. I'm guessing it was blocking composer? I also took some other steps: removing 64-bit wamp and everything from the path related to composer/php/apache then I installed 32-bit wamp and added back everything relevant to the path, I also uncommented from both `php.ini`s `extension=php_sockets.dll`. I saw booting in safe mode w/networking also worked for some. Might want to give it a try?

Comment: These links were kind of helpful too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23386205/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223943/ http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=14965

Comment: Got this working on my work PC now too, as we access the internet through a proxy I had to go to my system env variables add `HTTP_PROXY` with the proxy and port `proxy:8080` and it worked right away. Read more here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#http-proxy-or-http-proxy

Answer (score 0):

A point for WAMP users to be aware of:
WAMP has a task bar widget that has a UI to enable/disable various extensions in the php.ini. However this php.ini file is located under the Apache installation in WAMP. If the PHP installation directory is in the PATH environment variable, the php.ini file used by the command line instance of PHP is NOT THE SAME as the php.ini file used by the Apache installation in WAMP. In order to run the Composer installer you must edit the php.ini file that is under the PHP installation directory.