# Composer downloading error

Tags: php, composer-php, pear

When I execute:

```
composer install
```

I get the following output:

```
Loading composer repositories with package informati
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
The "http://packagist.org/p/phpunit/phpunit$abafcd02d9793416c76c78da3f1fafa0bc4da3ac1acec5c80e51d7904589ea30.json"
file could not be downloaded: send of 103 bytes failed with errno=10053
An established connection was aborted by the software installed on the host-computer.
(...)
```

On the network level I see, that the server send TCP packet with RST (Reset) flat set on.

Does anyone know what is wrong here?

My configuration:

- Windows 8.1
- Apache 2.4
- PHP 5.5.11
- PEAR Version: 1.9.4

php.ini:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll

allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = On
```

Comment: Possibly a related question: http://superuser.com/questions/630017/error-10053-using-composer - unfortunately without an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uninstalling **K9 Web Protection** software that I had on my computer was the solution for my problem.

Comment: This drove me nuts, thanks for the recommendation. Worked after the restart after removing k9.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. I am not 100% sure which of this two things worked, but it must have been one of them:

**1)** I booted in Safe mode (with network).

In safe mode I run:

```
composer install
```

worked fine.

**2)** Still in Safe Mode I run a registry repair tool in CCleaner application (it's a free app) and used clean option.

Then I booted in normal Windows 8 mode, I deleted vendor directory and composer.lock file that have been created in Safe Mode.

After this:

```
composer install
```

in Windows 8 works fine. At last!

**EDIT:**
False hope. Unfortunately it did not work for a long run. The problem still existed!