# Installing Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I am on a windows 8 machine and I'm trying to learn laravel. I copy and pasted my PHP folder from C:\xampp to C:\php, installed composer, ran `composer install`  then `composer create-project laravel/laravel learning-laravel`. So far everything was created so I went into the directory and tried to use 'php artisan serve' and got the following error.

```
C:\Users\denni_000\learning-laravel>php artisan serve
Warning: require(C:\Users\denni_000\learning-laravel\bootstrap/../vendor/autoloa
d.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\denni_000\l
earning-laravel\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
```

Comment: can you get `c:\>php --version` output in command prompt? if not, you need to add php to `PATH` Environment variable so that you can access it from `cmd`

Comment: try reinstalling Laravel or try to tell us what file is missing

Answer (score 5):

Why you copied php folder

1. download composer install it.
2. download laravel latest version and store it on your xampp/htdocs/laravel
3. and run cmd with composer install command

For more follow [install laravel on windows xampp](http://www.tutsnare.com/how-to-install-laravel-on-windows-xampp/)

or [Laravel 4.1 installation with composer in xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23881891/laravel-4-1-installation-with-composer-in-xampp)

Comment: Since it worked, maybe you could consider accepting the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Follow the installation guide from [Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0)

1. Install [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/):

   Like Laravel.com says: "Make sure to place the ~/.composer/vendor/bin directory in your PATH so the laravel executable can be located by your system."
2. Type the following statement in the command line:

   ```
   composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
   ```
3. Create a fresh Laravel project in a specified directory with the "laravel new" command:

   ```
   laravel new blog
   ```

   You can also create a Laravel project using composer, like such:

   ```
   composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For windows Simply download [Laragon](http://laragon.org/) which includes latest php 5.6.7, Apache, Mysql, Redis, Memcached an alternative to Xampp or Mamp with small size. Easy to install laravel and create project with auto create virtual host by it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

U need to go to the directory where laravel is installed and run the following command.

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Laravel 4.2 with composer:

```
sudo composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel project-directory-name 4.2 --prefer-dist
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different way to setup laravel, may be you guys will like it

**Step 1**:
Clone https://github.com/laravel/laravel or you may download zip also.

**Step 2**:
Navigate to downloaded folder in command prompt and run `composer install`

**Step 3**:
open the folder and rename `.env.example` to `.env` and update the credentials mentioned in file.

**Step 4**:
After these steps if you navigate to the directory from web-server it will cause an error `No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.` to fix this just run `php artisan key:generate`

Done!

Hope you guys like this way :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install all the laravel required dependency.

To do that, you need to tell composer to install everything needed.

Below is the command to use to install that's required in laravel composer.json.

```
composer install
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to learn laravel I seriously recommend you use laravel homestead with vagrant.

For this you need to:

1. Install [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).
2. Install [vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html).
3. Install [git](https://git-scm.com/downloads).
4. Install ssh.exe (Download [msysgit](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit) and copy the content of `bin folder` to `git bin folder`).
5. Install Homestead on Vagrant (Follow the steps on [laravel/homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead) documentation page).
6. Install Laravel on Homestead (Follow the steps on [laravel/installation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/installation) documentation page).

This method apply to Windows, Linux or Mac, only change the step 4 on linux or mac.