# New start with composer package dependencies?

Tags: php, dependencies, package, composer-php

I am trying to understand Composer/Package/Dependencies. I have known some basic of composer [here](http://grossi.io/2013/why-you-should-use-composer-and-how-to-start-using-it/) and how to install it on [windows and XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23881891/laravel-4-1-installation-with-composer-in-xampp).

I have successfully install PayPal rest [API](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sample-app-php/) package successfully and have some general quires:

1. What is dependency use? How to know what dependency I should use in a package? Or if I create my own package?
2. Where to get list of available dependency? Is dependency language portable?
3. Is there any predefined structure of package to build?
4. Which is good to use package/dependency or use libraries in custom code?
5. Is there anything to know get a good start?

I am confused with this new start?

Answer (score 0):

In short: Some points you should know ...

#### What is Composer?

Composer is a tool for dependency management in PHP. It allows you to declare the dependent libraries your project needs and it will install them in your project for you.

#### What is a Package?

Packages are usually third party libraries providing a specific functionality. Packages are aggregated in the common composer repository [Packagist.org](https://packagist.org/). This is the first address to look for packages.
A package is a library other projects can depend on.

#### What is a Project?

A project is something that *you* write. It is your PHP application.

#### What is a Dependency?

The dependency defines which third party packages your project does depend on. If your project for example needs the paypal rest API then you define a dependency for that in your project. You find a good introduction on how to define dependencies in your project at the [official composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md).

Here is a real example on how to create your first project:
http://www.dev-metal.com/composer-tutorial/

The basic usage guide from the composer docs is always a good first address to learn how composer works: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md